# MySQL query performance using INT/BIGINT and indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, int, database-performance, bigint

Here's the table I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `ip2_org_translators` (
  `ip_start` bigint(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_end` bigint(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ip_start` (`ip_start`,`ip_end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Note the index on `ip_start` and `ip_end`. Previously the `ip_start` and `ip_end` columns were int(10) FYI.

Here's the query I have:

```
SELECT organization FROM `ip2_org_translators` WHERE (1823194021 >= ip_start AND 1823194021 <= ip_end)
```

If I lower the number by a power of ten (to say 182319402) this query runs in the nominal 6-8ms range. **If however** the number larger (10 or more places) the query takes ~700ms to run. EXPLAINing this query gives

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE ip2_org_translators ALL ip_start NULL NULL NULL 1392767 Using where
```

Note that it's not using the `ip_start` index and instead does a full table scan.

Is this a bug in MySQL or my index / query?

Comment: it is 32bit or 64bit mysql?

Comment: @IlyaBursov Not sure actually.

Comment: check it via SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"; and if possible replace with 64 bit version (of course you need 64bit OS). I suppose you problem is because 32bit soft cannot work fast with 64 bit value (int - 32bit, bigint - 64bit), so when your numbers exceed 32bit range (about 2^32-1, it is about 4 billions) - they have to use more cpu instructions to compare 2 64bit numbers

Comment: @IlyaBursov innodb_version 1.2.10
protocol_version 10
slave_type_conversions 
version 5.6.10
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os osx10.7

Comment: Looks like 64 bit to me

Comment: ok, according to explain query do not use index, try to do `analyze ip2_org_translators; optimize ip2_org_translators;` - these will take time, prepare for downtime, then try again `explain extended`